# How to set style of the Toast

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

The toast is displayed on top of the tabs. How can I make a tab on top of a toast?[image]

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: I tried change `position` style and `z-index` style, but nothing helps, since the "toast" block is located above the block level of tabs

Answer (score 2):

The answer probably comes late, but in case somebody else will need to solve it:

HTML of ion-toast looks like this:

[ion-toast DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx5CJ.png)

There are:

- `ion-toast`: covers whole page as invisible wrapper for toast message itself
- `.toast-wrapper`: which represents the toast message itself, positioned within `ion-toast`

`.toast-wrapper` is inside of Shadow DOM and doesn't have `part` attribute set, so we can't manipulate with it.

But we can manipulate `ion-toast` element itself. So what you can do it to adjust it's size, so `.toast-wrapper` will be rendered at different place.

For example like this:

```
ion-toast {
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try overwriting this class in your scss file.

```
.toast-ios,.toast-md {
.toast-wrapper {
    &.toast-bottom {
        bottom: 46px;
    }
}
```

but you can put out of the scss page

for example:

```
 page {
 } 
 .toast-ios,.toast-md {
    .toast-wrapper {
        &.toast-bottom {
            bottom: 46px;
        }
    }
  }
```